Nextjs useSearchParams is not updated correctly
I created a simple React hook to update the search params:
import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export const useParams = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const setParams = (key: string, value: string) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams);
    params.set(key, value);
    router.replace(`${pathname}?${params}`);
  };

  return { setParams };
};

Then I use it in a client component:
export const Pagination = () => {
  const { setParams } = useParams();

  const handleChangePageSize = (size: number) => {    
    setParams("pageSize", size.toString());
  };

  const handleSetPage = (pageNumber: number) => {
    setParams("pageNumber", pageNumber.toString());
  };
// ... More code

My issue is that after handleChangePageSize is called and the pageSize param is set with a value, when then later handelSetPage is called, it's not aware of the pageSize, which was set. To be more precise, the hook lags by one change. If I remove the router.replace inside the hook (for testing), I can see that if I call handleChangePageSize twice, for example with values of 3, and then 6, then when I call handleSetPage, the params will have the value of 3, therefore it lags by one.
Why does it lag and how can I correct my hook?

Try making a state to track the param
import { useState } from "react";
import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export const useParams = () => {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const router = useRouter();
  const pathname = usePathname();

  const [params, setParamsState] = useState(new URLSearchParams(searchParams));

  const setParams = (key: string, value: string) => {
    const updatedParams = new URLSearchParams(params);
    updatedParams.set(key, value);
    setParamsState(updatedParams);
    router.replace(`${pathname}?${updatedParams.toString()}`);
  };

  return { setParams };
};

page.tsx
 const { setParams } = useParams();

  const handleChangePageSize = (size: number) => {
    setParams('pageSize', size.toString());
  };

  const handleSetPage = (pageNumber: number) => {
    setParams('pageNumber', pageNumber.toString());
  };


<button
        onClick={() => {
          handleChangePageSize(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
        }}
      >
        Set Page Size
      </button>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          handleSetPage(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
        }}
      >
        Set Page
      </button>


Thank you for your answer,, that's working, do you know why we need an additional state, and the useSearchParams hook is not enough?

The issue is the searchParams doesn't update immediately, so setParams uses outdated data on subsequent state calls. When we use a state variable to store the search params, update this state whenever setParams is called, ensuring it always uses the latest parameters

can you mark this as the answer

Yes, I just don't understand the WHY. Yes will mark it of course mate, thanks for your help

function useSearchParams() actually it works correctly. Because this function runs on the client side, you should set a log and then go to the browser to see the parameter changes. If you look in the console, it won't print
